# Query inside proc erroring out

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am getting an error while running this query:

```
SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys,
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type
 from
  (
  Select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by COLUMN_POSITION) as rn
    from
    (
     SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        nvl(get_expression(table_name, index_name, column_position, table_owner), column_name) AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
                      FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
           left join dba_ind_expressions ri using (table_name, index_name, column_position,table_owner)
                      WHERE
       di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT' AND
        di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP' AND
        partitioned = 'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        nvl(get_expression(table_name, index_name, column_position, table_owner), column_name) AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
           left join dba_ind_expressions ri using (table_name, index_name, column_position,table_owner)
    WHERE
        di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT' AND
       di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
        dip.composite != 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        nvl(get_expression(table_name,index_name, column_position, table_owner), column_name) AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_subpartitions dis
        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
           left join dba_ind_expressions ri using (table_name, index_name, column_position,table_owner)
    WHERE
      di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT' AND
       di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' ) t
)
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by index_name  = prior index_name
and rn = prior rn+1
start with rn =1 ;
```

The error is

```
Error at Command Line : 56 Column : 86
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
```

Comment: @Boneist updated the code(in weblink shared in body) as per your suggestions..but still not working...now new error..Error at Command Line : 53 Column : 40
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DI"."INDEX_OWNER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something like:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT di.index_name AS INDEX_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'clustered'
                     ELSE
                      'nonclustered'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE'
                          AND substr(di.index_name, 1, 3) = 'PK_' THEN
                      ', unique, primary key'
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN
                      ', unique'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN
                      ''
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END || ' located on PRIMARY' AS INDEX_DESCRIPTION,
                   NVL(get_expression(di.table_name, di.index_name, ci.column_position, di.table_owner), ci.column_name) AS INDEX_KEYS,
                   NULL AS INCLUDE_COLS,
                   NULL AS INDEX_FILTER,
                   NULL AS DATA_COMPRESSION,
                   NULL AS ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS,
                   di.table_name AS TABLE_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'CLUSTERED'
                     ELSE
                      'NONCLUSTERED'
                   END AS INDEX_TYPE,
                   ci.column_position
            FROM   dba_indexes di
            JOIN   dba_ind_columns ci
            ON     ci.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    ci.index_name = di.index_name
            LEFT   JOIN dba_ind_expressions ri ON di.table_name = ri.table_name
                                                  AND di.table_owner = ri.table_owner
                                                  AND di.index_name = ri.index_name
                                                  AND ci.column_position = ri.column_position
            WHERE  di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT'
            AND    di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP'
            AND    di.partitioned = 'NO'),
     t2 AS (SELECT di.index_name AS INDEX_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'clustered'
                     ELSE
                      'nonclustered'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE'
                          AND substr(di.index_name, 1, 3) = 'PK_' THEN
                      ', unique, primary key'
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN
                      ', unique'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN
                      ''
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END || ' located on PRIMARY' AS INDEX_DESCRIPTION,
                   NVL(get_expression(di.table_name, di.index_name, ci.column_position, di.table_owner), ci.column_name) AS INDEX_KEYS,
                   NULL AS INCLUDE_COLS,
                   NULL AS INDEX_FILTER,
                   NULL AS DATA_COMPRESSION,
                   NULL AS ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS,
                   di.table_name AS TABLE_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'CLUSTERED'
                     ELSE
                      'NONCLUSTERED'
                   END AS INDEX_TYPE,
                   ci.column_position
            FROM   dba_indexes di
            JOIN   dba_ind_partitions dip
            ON     dip.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    dip.index_name = di.index_name
            JOIN   dba_ind_columns ci
            ON     ci.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    ci.index_name = di.index_name
            LEFT   JOIN dba_ind_expressions ri ON di.table_name = ri.table_name
                                                  AND di.table_owner = ri.table_owner
                                                  AND di.index_name = ri.index_name
                                                  AND ci.column_position = ri.column_position
            WHERE  di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT'
            AND    di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP'
            AND    di.partitioned = 'YES'
            AND    dip.composite != 'YES'),
     t3 AS (SELECT di.index_name AS INDEX_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'clustered'
                     ELSE
                      'nonclustered'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE'
                          AND substr(di.index_name, 1, 3) = 'PK_' THEN
                      ', unique, primary key'
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN
                      ', unique'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN
                      ''
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END || ' located on PRIMARY' AS INDEX_DESCRIPTION,
                   NVL(get_expression(di.table_name, di.index_name, ci.column_position, di.table_owner), ci.column_name) AS INDEX_KEYS,
                   NULL AS INCLUDE_COLS,
                   NULL AS INDEX_FILTER,
                   NULL AS DATA_COMPRESSION,
                   NULL AS ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS,
                   di.table_name AS TABLE_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'CLUSTERED'
                     ELSE
                      'NONCLUSTERED'
                   END AS INDEX_TYPE,
                   ci.column_position
            FROM   dba_indexes di
            JOIN   dba_ind_partitions dip
            ON     dip.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    dip.index_name = di.index_name
            JOIN   dba_ind_subpartitions dis
            ON     dis.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    dis.index_name = di.index_name
            AND    dis.partition_name = dip.partition_name
            JOIN   dba_ind_columns ci
            ON     ci.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    ci.index_name = di.index_name
            LEFT   JOIN dba_ind_expressions ri ON di.table_name = ri.table_name
                                                  AND di.table_owner = ri.table_owner
                                                  AND di.index_name = ri.index_name
                                                  AND ci.column_position = ri.column_position
            WHERE  di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT'
            AND    di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP'
            AND    di.partitioned = 'YES'
            AND    dip.composite = 'YES'),
     t4 AS (SELECT *
            FROM   t1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM   t2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM   t3),
      t AS (SELECT index_name,
                   index_description,
                   index_keys,
                   include_cols,
                   index_filter,
                   data_compression,
                   allow_page_locks,
                   table_name,
                   index_type,
                   column_position,
                   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY index_name ORDER BY column_position) AS rn
            FROM   t4)
SELECT index_name,
     index_description,
     ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys, ','), ',') AS index_keys,
     include_cols,
     index_filter,
     data_compression,
     allow_page_locks,
     table_name,
     index_type
FROM   t
WHERE  connect_by_isleaf = 1
CONNECT BY index_name = PRIOR index_name
    AND    rn = PRIOR rn + 1
START  WITH rn = 1;
```

Note that I have split the 3 subqueries being unioned into their own subqueries using subquery factoring (aka CTEs). This is to make things easier to read - you can easily see the logic used to pull the results together by pulling the subqueries out into their own named subquery.

I believe the issue was you were using the `join ... using` format but the join conditions were referencing a column from a third table. By using `join ... on` and qualifying all the columns, the joins are explicit and they work.

However, I think you could probably replace `with t1 ... t2 ... t3 ... t4 ...` with:

```
WITH t4 AS (SELECT di.index_name AS INDEX_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'clustered'
                     ELSE
                      'nonclustered'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE'
                          AND substr(di.index_name, 1, 3) = 'PK_' THEN
                      ', unique, primary key'
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN
                      ', unique'
                   END || CASE
                     WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN
                      ''
                     ELSE
                      ''
                   END || ' located on PRIMARY' AS INDEX_DESCRIPTION,
                   --NVL(get_expression(di.table_name, di.index_name, ci.column_position, di.table_owner), ci.column_name) AS INDEX_KEYS,
                   NULL AS INCLUDE_COLS,
                   NULL AS INDEX_FILTER,
                   NULL AS DATA_COMPRESSION,
                   NULL AS ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS,
                   di.table_name AS TABLE_NAME,
                   CASE
                     WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN
                      'CLUSTERED'
                     ELSE
                      'NONCLUSTERED'
                   END AS INDEX_TYPE,
                   ci.column_position
            FROM   dba_indexes di
            LEFT OUTER JOIN   dba_ind_partitions dip
            ON     dip.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    dip.index_name = di.index_name
            LEFT OUTER JOIN   dba_ind_subpartitions dis
            ON     dis.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    dis.index_name = di.index_name
            AND    dis.partition_name = dip.partition_name
            JOIN   dba_ind_columns ci
            ON     ci.index_owner = di.owner
            AND    ci.index_name = di.index_name
            LEFT   JOIN dba_ind_expressions ri ON di.table_name = ri.table_name
                                                  AND di.table_owner = ri.table_owner
                                                  AND di.index_name = ri.index_name
                                                  AND ci.column_position = ri.column_position
            WHERE  di.table_owner = 'ROLLOUT'
            AND    di.table_name = 'TESTORACLE_TEMP')
```